# Trying to model character's t-shirt. Duplicating faces does not work as expected

Tags: modeling, dupli-groups

I am trying to create shirt for my first character.

When I press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate faces, it gives me that weird thing below the character that you can see on the second screenshot.

Any reason why?

I am on Blender 3.0 + Windows 10.

I use *Mirror* Modifier + *Subdivision Surface* (occasionally as it is performance heavy)

[image: Creating T-Shit]
[image: After pressing Shift+D]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is most probably because you have an active mirror modifier with clipping enabled and the merge threshold is rather large
I'd advise you to reduce the merge threshold in the mirror modifier to a lower value, like, say 0.01m